# How do I compact a virtual disk using pyVmomi?

Tags: python, vsphere, esxi, pyvmomi

In VirtualBox I have been using the command:

```
VBoxManage.exe modifymedium disk disk.vdi --compact
```

In order to reduce the size of .vdi files after running zerofree.  I'd like to do the same for vSphere virtual disks using pyVmomi.  I've seen you can use the command

```
vmkfstools --punchzero disk.vmdk
```

But this seems to require ESXi host shell access which I don't have.

Comment: Python scripts can run other executables using the built-in [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module (and pass arguments to them). Doing so doesn't necessary invoke the shell.

Comment: @martineau What I meant was, I don't have access to run vmkfstools on the host in question, so I need to do it through the API.  subprocess module won't help.  I've updated the description in case it wasn't clear.